# Build 32-bit Qt on 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: qt, cross-compiling

How do I build 32-bit Qt under 64-bit Linux? I have trouble with libraries, notably with x11 (“X11 functionality failed” message during configure). What packages do I have to install and what mkspec I have to use? I tried linux-g++-32, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the 32-bit X11 libraries installed? You'll probably have problems linking against 64-bit libraries.